# I want to edit a working javascript code to increase its functionality

Tags: javascript

please look at this page http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/ and view the demo. you will find out that when clicking on the mask the pop-up disappears. how can I make that clicking event optional and `true` by default like in this code;

`TINY.box.show({url:'advanced.html',width:300,height:150,`**maskclick:false**`})`

the whole javascript code to be edited:

```
TINY={};

TINY.box=function(){
var j,m,b,g,v,p=0;
return{
    show:function(o){
        v={opacity:70,close:1,animate:1,fixed:1,mask:1,maskid:'',boxid:'',topsplit:2,url:0,post:0,height:0,width:0,html:0,iframe:0};
        for(s in o){v[s]=o[s]}
        if(!p){
            j=document.createElement('div'); j.className='tbox';
            p=document.createElement('div'); p.className='tinner';
            b=document.createElement('div'); b.className='tcontent';
            m=document.createElement('div'); m.className='tmask';
            g=document.createElement('div'); g.className='tclose'; g.v=0;
            document.body.appendChild(m); document.body.appendChild(j); j.appendChild(p); p.appendChild(b);
            m.onclick=g.onclick=TINY.box.hide; window.onresize=TINY.box.resize
        }else{
            j.style.display='none'; clearTimeout(p.ah); if(g.v){p.removeChild(g); g.v=0}
        }
        p.id=v.boxid; m.id=v.maskid; j.style.position=v.fixed?'fixed':'absolute';
        if(v.html&&!v.animate){
            p.style.backgroundImage='none'; b.innerHTML=v.html; b.style.display='';
            p.style.width=v.width?v.width+'px':'auto'; p.style.height=v.height?v.height+'px':'auto'
        }else{
            b.style.display='none'; 
            if(!v.animate&&v.width&&v.height){
                p.style.width=v.width+'px'; p.style.height=v.height+'px'
            }else{
                p.style.width=p.style.height='100px'
            }
        }
        if(v.mask){this.mask(); this.alpha(m,1,v.opacity)}else{this.alpha(j,1,100)}
        if(v.autohide){p.ah=setTimeout(TINY.box.hide,1000*v.autohide)}else{document.onkeyup=TINY.box.esc}
    },
    fill:function(c,u,k,a,w,h){
        if(u){
            if(v.image){
                var i=new Image(); i.onload=function(){w=w||i.width; h=h||i.height; TINY.box.psh(i,a,w,h)}; i.src=v.image
            }else if(v.iframe){
                this.psh('<iframe src="'+v.iframe+'" width="'+v.width+'" frameborder="0" height="'+v.height+'"></iframe>',a,w,h)
            }else{
                var x=window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                x.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){p.style.backgroundImage=''; TINY.box.psh(x.responseText,a,w,h)}
                };
                if(k){
                    x.open('POST',c,true); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); x.send(k)
                }else{
                    x.open('GET',c,true); x.send(null)
                }
            }
        }else{
            this.psh(c,a,w,h)
        }
    },
    psh:function(c,a,w,h){
        if(typeof c=='object'){b.appendChild(c)}else{b.innerHTML=c}
        var x=p.style.width, y=p.style.height;
        if(!w||!h){
            p.style.width=w?w+'px':''; p.style.height=h?h+'px':''; b.style.display='';
            if(!h){h=parseInt(b.offsetHeight)}
            if(!w){w=parseInt(b.offsetWidth)}
            b.style.display='none'
        }
        p.style.width=x; p.style.height=y;
        this.size(w,h,a)
    },
    esc:function(e){e=e||window.event; if(e.keyCode==27){TINY.box.hide()}},
    hide:function(){TINY.box.alpha(j,-1,0,3); document.onkeypress=null; if(v.closejs){v.closejs()}},
    resize:function(){TINY.box.pos(); TINY.box.mask()},
    mask:function(){m.style.height=this.total(1)+'px'; m.style.width=this.total(0)+'px'},
    pos:function(){
        var t;
        if(typeof v.top!='undefined'){t=v.top}else{t=(this.height()/v.topsplit)-(j.offsetHeight/2); t=t<20?20:t}
        if(!v.fixed&&!v.top){t+=this.top()}
        j.style.top=t+'px'; 
        j.style.left=typeof v.left!='undefined'?v.left+'px':(this.width()/2)-(j.offsetWidth/2)+'px'
    },
    alpha:function(e,d,a){
        clearInterval(e.ai);
        if(d){e.style.opacity=0; e.style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)'; e.style.display='block'; TINY.box.pos()}
        e.ai=setInterval(function(){TINY.box.ta(e,a,d)},20)
    },
    ta:function(e,a,d){
        var o=Math.round(e.style.opacity*100);
        if(o==a){
            clearInterval(e.ai);
            if(d==-1){
                e.style.display='none';
                e==j?TINY.box.alpha(m,-1,0,2):b.innerHTML=p.style.backgroundImage=''
            }else{
                if(e==m){
                    this.alpha(j,1,100)
                }else{
                    j.style.filter='';
                    TINY.box.fill(v.html||v.url,v.url||v.iframe||v.image,v.post,v.animate,v.width,v.height)
                }
            }
        }else{
            var n=a-Math.floor(Math.abs(a-o)*.5)*d;
            e.style.opacity=n/100; e.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+n+')'
        }
    },
    size:function(w,h,a){
        if(a){
            clearInterval(p.si); var wd=parseInt(p.style.width)>w?-1:1, hd=parseInt(p.style.height)>h?-1:1;
            p.si=setInterval(function(){TINY.box.ts(w,wd,h,hd)},20)
        }else{
            p.style.backgroundImage='none'; if(v.close){p.appendChild(g); g.v=1}
            p.style.width=w+'px'; p.style.height=h+'px'; b.style.display=''; this.pos();
            if(v.openjs){v.openjs()}
        }
    },
    ts:function(w,wd,h,hd){
        var cw=parseInt(p.style.width), ch=parseInt(p.style.height);
        if(cw==w&&ch==h){
            clearInterval(p.si); p.style.backgroundImage='none'; b.style.display='block'; if(v.close){p.appendChild(g); g.v=1}
            if(v.openjs){v.openjs()}
        }else{
            if(cw!=w){p.style.width=(w-Math.floor(Math.abs(w-cw)*.6)*wd)+'px'}
            if(ch!=h){p.style.height=(h-Math.floor(Math.abs(h-ch)*.6)*hd)+'px'}
            this.pos()
        }
    },
    top:function(){return document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop},
    width:function(){return self.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth},
    height:function(){return self.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight},
    total:function(d){
        var b=document.body, e=document.documentElement;
        return d?Math.max(Math.max(b.scrollHeight,e.scrollHeight),Math.max(b.clientHeight,e.clientHeight)):
        Math.max(Math.max(b.scrollWidth,e.scrollWidth),Math.max(b.clientWidth,e.clientWidth))
    }
}
}();
```

Comment: Could you please invest a minimum of effort and post the coresponding bit of code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  SO is not really meant to be a "debug my code" site - if that's what you are looking for, you should probably hire someone to do it for you. If you have a *specific* technical question arising of your working on the issue, feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps replace

```
 m.onclick=g.onclick=TINY.box.hide;
```

with

```
g.onclick = TINY.box.hide;

if (v.maskclick !== false)
    m.onclick = TINY.box.hide;
```